# Bash - Weird white space error when printing variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

I am trying to create a private access token using the `rails-terminal` for GitLab using a bash script. I got the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

password=$(microk8s kubectl exec -it gitlab-6f6ff575cb-zvcph -n project-utility -- /bin/sh -c 'gitlab-rails runner "puts SecureRandom.hex(4)"')
user_token=$(microk8s kubectl exec -it gitlab-6f6ff575cb-zvcph -n project-utility -- /bin/sh -c 'gitlab-rails runner "user = User.new(name: \"Project\", username: \"System\", email: \"system@project.com\", password: \"'"$password"'\"); user.save!; token = user.personal_access_tokens.create(name: \"System\", scopes: [:api]); puts token.token"')

echo "Generated password: $password"
echo "Generated user token: $user_token"
```

Now this script does everyting correctly except that there is a warning in the response of the `user_token`. The response is as folows:

```
Generated password: 9f9857cc
Generated user token: /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/runner/runn in middle of line, treated as a mere space
glpat-VuHcqsoK8XkAMq1fhVTS
```

Now I have tried stripping the white-spaces using this:

```
user_token="${user_token##* }"
user_token="${user_token%% *}"
echo "Generated user token: $user_token"
```

This removes the warning, but prints a random `space` word in the output:

```
Generated password: 8465390c
Generated user token: space
glpat-Rzoz_Zn8xJ_9kVt1dVek
```

I also tried the following line to strip whitespaces:

```
user_token="$(echo "$user_token" | tr -d '[:space:]')"
echo "Generated user token: $user_token"
```

But this returns the warning again, but then without any spaces in the sentence...

The output I am trying to get is this ofcourse:

```
Generated password: 8465390c
Generated user token: glpat-Rzoz_Zn8xJ_9kVt1dVek
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would examine the string being constructed from your password more closely before you actually execute the command.

Comment: Running only the password command and printing the value in a file returns the following: `08e4abfc`. No whitespaces or empty lines before/after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the `"${user_token##* }"`. This ignores the fact that a newline can be included in the output (which it is). So, you are only gobbling everything up until `space<newline>glpat-...`. To fix this, one option is to use `cut`:

```bash
user_token=$(cut -d $'\n' -f 2 <<< "$user_token")
user_token="${user_token%% *}"
echo "Generated user token: $user_token"
```

Of course, this assumes the filepath that's printed doesn't have any newlines, but I don't think that's a practical issue.

A better solution is to modify what you are already doing:

```bash
user_token="${user_token##*$'\n'}"
user_token="${user_token##* }"
user_token="${user_token%% *}"
echo "Generated user token: $user_token"
```

Comment: The second code block returns the output with the word `space` again, like I described above...? I changed the word `var` to `user_token`, else my code creashes with `exit code 1`

Comment: Hmm, are you on an older version of Bash like 3.2? I'm on latest and it worked perfectly (I updated the second code block to use the right variables)

Comment: I am running on: `5.1.16(1)-release`

Comment: Hm, that's weird. I used `user_token='/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/runner/runn in middle of line, treated as a mere space
glpat-VuHcqsoK8XkAMq1fhVTS'` as a test string, and received the intended result.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what else could be happening. Hopefully the first code block at least works

Comment: Okay when I overwrite the password manually as variable using: `password="08e4abfc"`, I get the wanted result, but when it is auto-generated, the result is with the word `space`.... I cannot see any whitespaces or empty lines around the generated password, but manually assigning the same value does work... Any idea?

Comment: I sort of doubt that any space would be a non-ASCII space character, so I'm not really sure. Windows different in newline endings wouldn't give you the result you're getting either. So you're probably going to have to inspect the output with a hex editor and see what's up because I'm not sure...

Comment: I have fixed it by removing the second filter line and added: `2>&1 | grep -o "glpat-[a-zA-Z0-9]*"` at the end of the command